# ZF2 tablegateway on select shows error "unknown column"

Tags: zend-framework2

Title says it.
It says that i dont have a columnd 'user_id' but i have. It works with 'id'.

This is the problem function :

```
public function getUploadsByUserId($userId)
{
    $userId = (int) $userId;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(
        array('user_id' => $userId));


    return $rowset;
}
```

This is the model:

```
namespace Users\Model;

use Zend\View\Model\ConsoleModel;

class Upload
{
public $id;
public $filename;
public $label;
public $user_id;


public function getArrayCopy()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}

function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->filename = (isset($data['filename'])) ? $data['filename'] : null;
    $this->label = (isset($data['label'])) ? $data['label'] : null;
    $this->user_id = (isset($data['user_id'])) ? $data['user_id'] : null;

}
}
```

Where can be the problem here, its clearly that i have such column.

Comment: Can you share the table schema?

Comment: Problem solved it was a tiny mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was not configured the tablegateway correctly. It was 'user' instead of 'uploads' .

```
 'UploadTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Upload());

                    return new TableGateway('uploads', $dbAdapter, null,
                        $resultSetPrototype);
                },
```

Comment: You can approve your answer.